# How to get site ip address using c

Tags: c, sockets, http, ip

I am trying to build a HTTP request using sockets in c.
So, in order to navigate the socket to the correct site ip.
I need to get the site ip.
I have managed to get the host ip but that not always work.
The following code gets the host ip:

```
host = gethostbyname(host_name);
if (host != NULL) {
    memcpy(&inp, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    sprintf(ip, "%s", inet_ntoa(inp));
}
```

But that not always work, for example if I want to send the socket to stackoverflow.com and get his HTML content.I used this code and the output was: "198.252.206.16".
And if you enter that ip you can see that it is a wrong ip,so what can I do?
Please help.

P.S that this all my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s domain_name\nE.g. %s www.yahoo.com/lalal.html\n", argv[0], argv[0]);
        return(0);
    }

struct protoent *pr;
struct in_addr inp;
int x = 1;
int ret;
char buf[4192];
char ip[16];
struct hostent *host;
int sock, bytes_recieved;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

char url[strlen(argv[1])];
strcpy(url,argv[1]);
char *index_page = strstr(argv[1], "/");
char *host_name = strtok(url,"/");
char message[4000];
sprintf(message,"GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n",index_page,host_name);
printf("%s",message);

host = gethostbyname(host_name);
if (host != NULL) {
    memcpy(&inp, host->h_addr_list[0], host->h_length);
    sprintf(ip, "%s", inet_ntoa(inp));
}
else {
    printf("ERROR - Host ip was not found.\n\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("%s\n",ip);

pr = getprotobyname("tcp");
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("Socket");
    exit(1);
}
printf("%s\n",message);
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);   
server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8); 

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
    perror("Connect");
    exit(1);
}

write(sock, message, strlen(message));

while ((ret = read(sock, buf, 4192)) != 0) {
    buf[ret]='\0';
    fwrite(buf, ret, sizeof(char), stdout);
    x++;
}

if (close(sock) == -1)
    printf("Close socket error\n");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: When I do `nslookup 198.252.206.16`, I get `stackoverflow.com`.  So I'm afraid I cannot "see that it is a wrong ip".

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to send the socket to stackoverflow.com"?

Comment: @indiv If you enter that ip that send you to STACKEXCHANGE site
and there is written: "Couldn't find 198.252.206.16"

Comment: @user3774164: See my answer, which covered that error.

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange hosts multiple sites on the same server.  `198.252.206.16` is the IP address of that server, and that is the correct IP address you need to connect your socket to.

When requesting an HTTP resource from a site that resides on a shared server, you must provide an HTTP `Host` header to specify the site's hostname so the server knows which site you are trying to access.

For example, if you go to `http://198.252.206.16`, the request would look like this:

```
(connect to 198.252.206.16)

GET / HTTP 1.1
Host: 198.252.206.16
...
```

If you go to `http://www.stackoverflow.com`, the request looks like this:

```
(connect to 198.252.206.16)

GET / HTTP 1.1
Host: www.stackoverflow.com
...
```

If you go to `http://www.stackexchange.com`, the request looks like this:

```
(connect to 198.252.206.16)

GET / HTTP 1.1
Host: www.stackexchange.com
...
```

Notice that they all connect to the same IP address.

There is no site associated with the `198.252.206.16` host, which is why you get the error message.

The `Host` header is required for all HTTP 1.1 requests, and is optional for HTTP 1.0 requests (but an HTTP 1.0 request will fail in this situation if the `Host` header is missing).  It was designed specifically to support multiple sites on a shared server.

Comment: I know every thing that you mentioned.
I am not sure but i think I need to navigate the socket to what ip address to send the socket too,right?
If not, so how the socket knows to what site to enter?
And by the way, I have did already what you have mentioned and the socket just returns nothing.
thank you.

Comment: Obviously not, or you would not be having your problem in the first place. The `gethostbyname()` result you showed is correct for StackOverflow, so you must not be sending a proper HTTP request to access StackOverflow vs other StackExchange sites. Please show your actual HTTP request code.

Comment: Here is my HTTP request:
GET /questions/26305618/how-to-get-site-ip-address-using-c/26306431 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n

Comment: I did not ask to see your request data, I asked to see your code that is creating the request. My guess is that you are not adding the `Host` header correctly, so it does not get sent to the server. Use a packet sniffer, like WireShark, to verify.

Comment: ok, I will add all my code to the post.
But I think I am making the request right because I have tried it on over websites and that works.